# echo не выводится в тегах html

Tags: php, html, css

Есть строки кода:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'event-type'); 
$name = $terms[0]->name;
```

Вывожу результат:

```
$content .= '<div class="dk"><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
    echo $name;
$content .= '</div>';
```

И результат выводиться но вне div`a класса dk, а вылазит в самом верху страницы отдельно.

Comment: Буквально по анкедоту, "доктор, когда я делаю так, то мне больно. А вы не делайте!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так делать:

```
$content .= '<div class="dk"><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
$content .= $name;
$content .= '</div>';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]